How are multiple cache-control lines interpreted?
These HTTP headers were returned from a request to a website I am responsible for:
cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
cache-control: max-age=300

I read somewhere that the most restrictive is taken. Is this right?  Or is the last one taken? Or are they merged?
I want to know how cache-control behaves when multiple headers are set to see if it could cause issues the way it is currently written. If it could, I'd like to get it to a single line.

According to RFC 2616:

It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma.

Therefore, that leads me to believe that your example:
cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
cache-control: max-age=300

should be interpreted equivalently to this:
cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, max-age=300

Then, looking at RFC 7234, we see:

When there is more than one value present for a given directive
(e.g., two Expires header fields, multiple Cache-Control: max-age
directives), the directive's value is considered invalid.  Caches are
encouraged to consider responses that have invalid freshness
information to be stale.

Therefore, this leads me to believe that your example, by RFC, could be further simplified to this:
cache-control: private, must-revalidate

Or possibly even that the entire cache-control section should be ignored. The RFC is not entirely clear to me.
Now in reality, I believe the way a cache interprets this malformed header will not follow the RFC recommendations, but will instead vary by implementation. I have reason to believe web browsers might typically honor the last value listed in the directive (in this case max-age=300), rather than invalidating the whole thing as the RFC suggests.
In any case, I'd say this is important to fix. There's no reason it should be ambiguous as it currently is!

Additional source:
Are Duplicate HTTP Response Headers acceptable? - Stack Overflow

Thanks for the explanation.  We definitely will have to trace down where the 2 are coming from, because being ambiguous about this is not what we want.
